# "Самое выгодное предложение в Москве!" Какое это предложение?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> "Самое выгодное предложение в Москве!"

Это неполное или номинативное предложение?

Comment: “Самое выгодное предложение в Москве!” Вопрос: Какое это предложение? Ответ: Самое выгодное в Москве" :)

Answer (score 2):

Если это начало объявления, то это **именительный темы.**

Чтобы оно было неполным двусоставным, оно должно быть включено в диалог или быть парцеллированной конструкцией:

*-Это выгодное предложение?*

*-Да! Самое выгодное предложение в Москве!*

Парцеллят: Да, ребята, это было выгодное предложение! Самое выгодное предложение в Москве!

Было бы неполным двусоставным и с тире вместо сказуемого: *Самое выгодное предложение -  в Москве!*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, [ответ справочной службы.](https://ask.fm/russian/answers/150548864572) Мне кажется этот случай неполным предложением (т.к. неизвестен товар, который самый выгодный). Именительный темы - это разве не другой случай, связанный больше с выразительными средствами и фигурами речи?

Comment: А почему неизвестен товар? Вы откуда взяли предложение? Чаще всего его используют в рекламе, а там товар известен. Потому я и говорю, что это именительный темы, дальше ведь о нём будет речь. В рекламе сначала зазывают: Вот самое выгодное предложение! Купите этот товар! Если мы подставляем "вот" - это именительный темы, форма односоставного номинативного. Если подставляем "это" - неполное двусоставное с пропуском подлежащего ЭТО. Нужна ситуация.

Answer (score 1):

Это номинативное предложение, оно не может быть неполным. Для того чтобы быть неполным, ему стоит стать хотя бы двусоставным. В нашем же случае даже не приходится говорить о нулевом члене предложения.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, [ответ справочной службы.](https://ask.fm/russian/answers/150548864572) Мне кажется этот случай неполным предложением (т.к. неизвестен товар, который самый выгодный).

Comment: @SergG аргументация справочный службы впечатляет! Скажите, а как известность/неизвестность товара влияет на синтаксис?